# How to set permalink of your blog post according to date and title of post?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am having this website http://www.finalyearondesk.com . My blogs post link are set like this.. http://www.finalyearondesk.com/index.php?id=28 . I want it to set like this ... finalyearondesk.com/2011/09/22/how-to-recover-ubuntu-after-it-is-crashed/ .

I am using the following function to get these posts...

```
function get_content($id = '') {

    if($id != ""):
        $id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
        $sql = "SELECT * from cms_content WHERE id = '$id'";
        $return = '<p><a href="http://www.finalyearondesk.com/">Go back to Home page</a></p>';
        echo $return;

    else:
        $sql = "select * from cms_content ORDER BY id DESC";

    endif;

    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($res) != 0):

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            echo '<h1><a href="index.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['title'] . '</a></h1>';
            echo '<p>' . "By: " . '<font color="orange">' . $row['author'] . '</font>' . ", Posted on: " . $row['date'] . '<p>';
            echo '<p>' . $row['body'] . '</p><br />';
        }

    else:

        echo '<p>We are really very sorry, this page does not exist!</p>';

    endif;
}
```

And I am using this code to dispaly it on my index.php page...

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) :
        $obj -> get_content($_GET['id']);
    else :
        $obj -> get_content_summary();
    endif;
?>
```

Any suggestions how to do this? And can we do this by using .htaccess?

Comment: You can use mod_rewrite in the .htaccess if it's enabled on your server.

Comment: But this would be for a single post? Or tell me how to do this? How wordpress do it?

Comment: I've never worked with wordpress so I wouldn't know. Are you familiar with regular expressions? You can use rewrite rules with regular expression capturing groups to do this.

Comment: see this, i want to achieve something like this  http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/rewrite-underscores-to-hyphens-for-seo-url.html

Comment: You might also consider checking out http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unfortunate thing about using mod_rewrite is that the data you are supplying in the form of a url is not the best way to query a database. But none the less you have year, month, day and title variables so you will need to rewrite your get_content function to query soomething like (depending on how you date is stored in the database.):

```
select * from cms_content 
   WHERE date='mktime(0,0,0,$month,$day,$year)'
   AND title='$title'
 ORDER BY id DESC
```

.htaccess would be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$  index.php?year=$1&month=$2&day=$3&title=$4
```

Comment: Actually, I am not having column year, month, day. Rather I have a column named "date" as  timestamp. so how to do this now?